# Books for very high level vegan cooking?

Tags: vegan, cookbook

I'm looking for a book, or some books on cooking vegan on a very high level. There are several nonvegan michelin star level books, and many "quick and lazy" books, but I'm having a hard time to find one that covers vegan dishes on star niveau.

Can someone recommend a book like this?

If there are books that contain a lot of vegetarian receipts that can be "veganized" without destroying the whole meal, that would be fine aswell :)

Comment: Instead of searching for ‘vegan’ cookbooks, you might try searching for ‘Shōjin ryōri’ (Buddhist temple cuisine).  There are a fair number of vegan Indian cookbooks, too, as there are castes that traditionally didn’t eat animal products.

Comment: You might clarify what you mean by ‘high level’. Are you looking for technical stuff like the optimal pH for aquafaba? Or for complex vegan recipes which assume and require a high degree of competence?

Comment: Good point! I thought more of high degree of competence stuff

Comment: Another way to search would be to see if any highly-rated vegan restaurants have published a cookbook; restaurant cookbooks tend to be aimed at a fairly competent, 'foodie' audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend [*Crossroads*](https://www.workman.com/products/crossroads), by vegan chef Tal Ronnen.  While not quite *The French Laundry Cookbook*, *Crossroads* is nevertheless on the very gourmet side of vegan.  And I can attest that the recipes are pretty good.